# Recursion problem in C

Tags: c, recursion

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days now but it seems I haven't grasped the concept of recursion,yet.

I have to build a program in C (recursion is a must here but loops are allowed as well) which does the following:
The user inputs 2 different strings.For example: 
String 1 - ABC
String 2 - DE

The program is supposed to print strings which are combined of the ones the user has entered.
the rule is that the inner order of the letters in each string (1&2) must remain.
That's the output for string1=ABC & string2=DE ":

abcde
abdce
abdec
adbce
adbec
adebc
dabce
dabec
daebc
deabc

If anyone could give me a hand here, it would be great.
Thanks guys.

Comment: I think people would be more tempted to help if you show what you already have.

Comment: thanks all of you who helped me out on this one.
yes,it is homework. i was not familiar with the site's policy for homework questions,next time i'll post in an appropriate way. for all the scepticals who reckon it's just gonna be copy&paste from here on, sorry to disappoint you, you got the wrong guy here.
Again, thanks a lot people for your help!
Jake

Comment: Glad to hear it Jake! And don't forget to accept an answer if one answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial solution in Java: it should be instructive:

```
public class Join {                                       // prints:
   static void join(String s, String s1, String s2) {     // ABCde
      if (s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty()) {                 // ABdCe
         System.out.println(s + s1 + s2);                 // ABdeC
      } else {                                            // AdBCe
         join(s + s1.charAt(0), s1.substring(1), s2);     // AdBeC
         join(s + s2.charAt(0), s1, s2.substring(1));     // AdeBC
      }                                                   // dABCe
   }                                                      // dABeC
   public static void main(String[] args) {               // dAeBC
      join("", "ABC", "de");                              // deABC
   }
}
```

#### How it works

Basically you have `String s`, the "output stream", and `String s1, s2`, the "input stream". At every opportunity, you first take from `s1`, and later you try again and take from `s2`, exploring both options recursively.

If at any time either "input stream" is empty, then you're left with no other choice but take whatever's left (if any).

Answer (score 3):

Here it is in C, based on the same idea @polygenelubricants used. It's not that I stole his idea, it's that this is a classical problem and this is the simplest approach :).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void solve(const char *str1, const char *str2,
           const int length1, const int length2,
           char *output, int pozOut, int pozIn1, int pozIn2)
{
    if (pozIn1 == length1 && pozIn2 == length2)
    {
        printf("%s\n", output);
        return;
    }

    if (pozIn1 < length1)
    {
        output[pozOut] = str1[pozIn1];
        solve(str1, str2, length1, length2, output, pozOut + 1, pozIn1 + 1, pozIn2);
    }

    if (pozIn2 < length2)
    {
        output[pozOut] = str2[pozIn2];
        solve(str1, str2, length1, length2, output, pozOut + 1, pozIn1, pozIn2 + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char temp[100]; // big enough to hold a solution.
    solve("ABC", "12", strlen("ABC"), strlen("12"), temp, 0, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

This can be improved. For example, how would you get rid of some of the parameters?
Also, this has a bug: you should make sure that `output` contains a `'\0'` at the end before printing it, otherwise you might get unexpected results. I'll leave that for you to fix.

Comment: @IVlad: LOL don't worry about "stealing" anything from me; I won't downvote you (I don't downvote at all anymore, period), and I think most people won't either. Stackoverflow is for knowledge, not drama. +1!

Comment: @Neil: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions "Don't downvote others who answer homework questions in good faith"

Comment: @Poly From the same source "It's usually better not to provide a complete code sample"

Comment: @Neil: `true`, which is why mine isn't complete, and is in a different language to boot. But someone downvoted anyway. I assumed that it was you, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Sigh. How do you know it doesn't help him? Plenty of official solutions to contest problems have helped me understand problems that I had no idea how to approach before. I've learned a lot from those solutions and have managed to use the ideas I picked up from there in other problems as well. I'm done discussing politics on meta. I think it helps and I also think homework questions are no different than other questions. Someone interested will take this code, try to understand, then try to rewrite it on their own, then try to improve it. Someone who's not interested won't get far anyway.

Comment: @IVlad: I tend to agree with you, but not here. This is clearly an algorithmic problem. The OP doesn't say "I know what to do but can't find out how to do it in `C`". It is likely that, having the solution he'll take the easy road and just copy-paste it without understanding the logic underneath.

Comment: There's a bug in this code: it assumes temp[] is initialised to 0, which is not guaranteed for local variables.

Comment: @ereOn: it's possible, true. But like I said, if he's like that he won't get far anyway. If he's the kind of student that will try to understand the solution, then this will have helped him. Either way, he stands to win more than I stand to lose (I lost a few seconds writing this program). @Paul: true. I'll point that out in my post but won't fix it, that should make the OP think at least a little.

Answer (score 2):

I don't feel like I want to write down the whole algorithm. However, here are some leads that might help you.

Basically, you must merge two strings, keeping the characters order. It's like you have 2 stacks of possibly different sizes.

In your example:

```
stack #1: A B C
stack #2: D E
```

You also know that the resulting string will have as length the sum of the length of the two input strings. (So you know already how much length to allocate)

If you proceed character by character: each turn you can choose wether to pop one character from either the stack #1 or the stack #2, then continue. (Here could be the recursion). If you roll up all the possible calls you'll have all the resulting strings.

I use to like problems like that when I was in college: it can seem difficult sometimes, but it is *so* rewarding when you solve it by yourself !

Feel free to comment if you need more clues.

Answer (score 2):

The same algorithm as IVlad, but dynamically allocating the result array, and using pointers rather than indexes making it a bit clearer I think.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void solve(const char* result, const char* x0, const char* x1, char* p) {
    if (!*x0 && !*x1) printf("%s\n", result);
    if (*x0) {
        *p = *x0;
        solve(result, x0 + 1, x1, p + 1);
    } 
    if (*x1) {
        *p = *x1;
        solve(result, x0, x1 + 1, p + 1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc >= 3) {
        size_t total_length = strlen(argv[1]) + strlen(argv[2]) + 1;
        char *result = malloc(total_length);
        if (result) {
            result[total_length - 1] = '\0';
            solve(result, argv[1], argv[2], result);
            free(result);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice code sample but I highly doubt the OP will have access to SO during his next exam ;)